# Xcode's IB cannot show up my custom view?

Tags: xcode6

Xcode's IB cannot show up my custom view?

Recently, i updated my Xcode to Version 6.4 (6E35b) and encounter an IB problem.

Before i update my xcode, all my custom view (extend uiview) can show up in IB.

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // 1. setup any properties here

    // 2. call super.init(coder:)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // 3. Setup view from .xib file
    xibSetup()
}
```

Currently, I cannot see my custom view in IB. But it can work well during the run time.

How can I make them show up in my IB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got a solution.
It not caused by my update of Xcode.
It caused by my closed the "Auto-Refresh" feature within IB.

So the solution is: Xcode -> Editor -> Refresh All Views
Then i think you will see all your custom view within IB.